# Heavy mysql usage CPU or Memory

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon s3 instance and the project we have on the server does a lot of INSERTs and UPDATEs and a few complex SELECTs

We are finding that MySQL will quite often take up a lot of the CPU.

**I am trying to establish whether a higher memory or higher cpu is better of the above setup.**

Below is an output of `cat /proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:      7347752 kB
MemFree:         94408 kB
Buffers:         71932 kB
Cached:        2202544 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:        6483248 kB
Inactive:       415888 kB
SwapTotal:           0 kB
SwapFree:            0 kB
Dirty:          168264 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:     4617848 kB
Mapped:          21212 kB
Slab:           129444 kB
SReclaimable:    86076 kB
SUnreclaim:      43368 kB
PageTables:      54104 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:   3673876 kB
Committed_AS:  5384852 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       180 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359738187 kB
```

**Current Setup:**

> High-CPU Extra Large Instance
>
> 7 GB of memory 20 EC2 Compute Units (8
>   virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute
>   Units each) 1690 GB of instance
>   storage 64-bit platform I/O
>   Performance: High API name: c1.xlarge

**Possible Setup:**

> High-Memory Double Extra Large
>   Instance
>
> 34.2 GB of memory 13 EC2 Compute Units (4 virtual cores with 3.25 EC2 Compute
>   Units each) 850 GB of instance storage
>   64-bit platform I/O Performance: High
>   API name: m2.2xlarge

Comment: are the tables all/predominantly MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: InnoDb for most tables... I have kept MyISAM on the 1 table we perform full text searches on

Comment: have you tried using mk-query-digest (in maatkit) or mtop to determine where the resource usage is heaviest?  the slow query log and the query profiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go for 32GB memory and maybe more harddisks in RAID. CPU won't help that much - you have eough cpu power. You also need to configure mysql correctly.

- Leave 1-2 GB for OS cache and for temp tables.
- Increase tmp_table_size
- remove swap
- optimize query_cache_size (don't make it too big - see mysql documentation about it)
- periodically run FLUSH QUERY CACHE. if your query cache is <512 MB - run it every 5 minutes. This **doesn't clean the cache**, it optimizes it (defragment). This is from mysql docs:

> Defragment the query cache to better
>   utilize its memory. FLUSH QUERY CACHE
>   does not remove any queries from the
>   cache, unlike FLUSH TABLES or RESET
>   QUERY CACHE.

However I noticed that the other solution has the half disk space: 850GB, which might be reduced number of hard disks. That's generally a bad idea. The biggest problem in databases is hard disks. If you use RAID5 - make sure you don't use less hard disks. If you don't use raid at all - I would suggest raid 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use `vmstat` and `iostat` to find out whether CPU or I/O is the bottleneck (if I/O - add more RAM and load data into memory). Run from shell and check results:

```
vmstat 5
iostat -dx 5
```

- if CPU is the problem `vmstat` will show high values in `us` column, and `iostat` will show low disk use (`util`)
- if I/O is the problem then `vmstat` will show low values in `us` column and `iostat` will show high disk utilization (`util`); by high I mean >50%

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application.

You could use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to cache mysql queries. This would ease cpu usage a bit, however with this method you would want to increase RAM for storing the queries.

On the other hand if it's not feasible based on type of application then I would recommend higher CPU.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many reasons for a MySQL to use a lot of CPU: It is either processing of stored routines (stored procedures or stored functions) or sorting going on that can eat CPU.

If you are using a lot of CPU due to stored routines, you are doing it wrong and your soul cannot be saved anyway.

If you are using a lot of CPU due to sorting going on, some things can be done, depending on the nature of your queries: You can extend indexes to include the ORDER BY columns at the end, or you can drop the ORDER BY clauses and sort in the client.

What approach to chose depends on the actual cause of the CPU usage - is it queries and sorting? And on the actual queries. So in any case you will need better monitoring first.

Not having monitoring information, the general advice is always: Buy more memory, not more CPU for a database.

Comment: are you implying sprocs are bad ?

Comment: In MySQL, the implementation is pretty horrible. The code is not parsed, the ASCII source of the procedure is stored on disk. Each connection parses the procedure and caches the parsed code in its connection structure, there is no sharing between connections. Additionally, the implementation is incomplete (somewhat corrected in 5.5) and hard to debug. Even without these problems, stored procedures are code that is running on the most expensive and least easily scaled CPUs in a system, and hence are generally a bad idea (counterexamples exist).

Comment: and yet, it will still be significantly faster (and require less network resources) than bringing the data to your app to do the processing and then sending he results back over the network

Comment: guess i'd better stick to 100's of middle tier to db svr calls then

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the on-demand nature of EC2 make it rather straightforward to rent the possible setup for a day, and do some load testing? Measurements speak louder than words.

Answer (score 0):

Use "High-CPU Extra Large Instance".

In your current setup, MySQL is not constrained by memory:

```
MemTotal:      7347752 kB    
MemFree:         94408 kB    
Buffers:         71932 kB    
Cached:        **2202544 kB**
```

Out of 7 GB memory, 2 GB is unused and being used by OS as I/O cache.

In this case, increasing CPU count would give you more bang for buck.